# How to get value from text by javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get **value** from

```
 <input type="text" name="Phone[]" id="Phone">
```

by **javascript**. How to do it?
please help me.

Comment: a simple google search would have given you this. Plus please also mention in the question what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is me who don't know HTML5 enough but what do you mean by "element Array".

The value of an input text is, if I am not mistaken, always a String so there is no array.

if you want all the inputs with a special class and then get the values as an array, you can do it like that:

```
$("input .phone").each(function(elem){return elem.val();});
```

and this will be an array of string

Did I answer your question?

Comment: I have a button to add phonenumber and remove it , how i can check phonenumber in  input by javascript ? i mean about it . and sorry to Ask question not clear.